# Sql request "not null"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, null

I have table with colums id, name, email, message, phone, links and login.
Login can be null(empty).

Its my sql request:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPassword);
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM `form` WHERE login NOT NULL ');
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

whith this error

```
 Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object
```

Its error with "WHERE login NOT NULL", i know. How me correctly make this request?

Comment: You are getting a query error. use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `NOT NULL`

Comment: never assume a query has succeeded. **ALWAYS** check the return values from a DB operation. There's exactly **ONE** way for queries to succeed, and far far far too many ways for things to fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

missing an `IS`

```
SELECT * FROM `form` WHERE login IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `IS NOT NULL` instead of just `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

"WHERE login IS NOT NULL"